# Android - EditText in ListView and OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView that contains an EditText widget in each row. The user can update the numeric value in the EditText, and once the focus is lost on that EditText, I want a TextView updated on the screen that contains the sum. I'm using the below code to check if the focus has been lost, but it every time I put focus on an EditText, it enters the if statement, and I think that has to do with the fact it is contained within a ListView. I'd like it to only enter the if statement when the user removes the focus from the EditText.

```
MyEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (!hasFocus) {
            //Perform Calculation
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `MyEditText`? How is it initialized? And where is the sum displayed? Can the user see it at the same time they are editing the EditTexts in the ListView?

Comment: Yes, the user can see it when they are editing the EditText. It is displayed at the top of the activity layout. MyEditText is initialized in the adapter: EditText MyEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.list_my_edit_text);